# Tool chain for proprietary communication protocol

Tags: monitoring, toolchain, can-bus, communication-protocol, canoe

I (the company rather) have a protocol implementation which uses the CAN hardware (CAN Transceiver). The protocol itself is not a standard CAN protocol stack. Is it possible to use any of the off the shelf CAN-bus monitors for debugging and investigating the data in the bus? I intend to see the bytes being transmitted and more importantly the other information like cycle time, frequency, delay, jitter (if any) and so on. Ofcourse more information is good and in-case some of these above mentioned parameters are missing, its still acceptable. The main purpose of the project is to show that the proprietary implementation is better (performance, bandwidth, speed, etc) than standard CAN stack while still using the CAN hardware (transceivers).

Comment: This should be asked on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ . A similar question is already asked there http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79521/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-debug-canbus-from-a-pc

Comment: That link is not useful but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think most commercial available CAN analyzers can do what you need. Look if they offer an option for programability, in order to provide the possibility to make your own interpretation of the CAN frames.

Can-Wiki offers a [list](http://www.can-wiki.info/doku.php?id=testequipment:cananalyzers)

http://www.emtas.de/en/produkte/can-interpreter